Is there a defined constant for In .NET Framework 4.8 Stream.CopyToAsync() method
The .NET Framework 4.8 Stream.CopyToAsync() method has a default buffer size of 81,920. I think that buffer size is fine but I also want to pass a cancellation token. To pass a token I also have to provide a buffer size.
stream.CopyToAsync(fs, 81920, token);
Is the default buffer size defined as a constant that I can use or do I have to create my own constant?

As per reference sources the constant exists, but it is private. So, for net 4.8 there is no way except to copy & paste the raw value 81920 into your code.
P.S. for the net core 2.1+ there is a separate overload CopyToAsync(Stream, CancellationToken) which do exactly what you need.
